# Base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cv::Mat’ sourceAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1] = matA->getValueData(fila,columna);

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello I am compiling a package, during compilation I encountered some problem due to data type conversion. After searching I found some similar issues but that could not help me. I am not very good at C++ programming. Your help will be highly appreciated.
The code is more than 3 hundred lines but I will post only the part where error occurred.
The error is:

```
    aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp: In member function ‘int CVG::Matrix::pseudoinverse(CVG::Matrix*)’:
/home/ibrrahim/catkin_workspaces/aerostack_catkin_ws/src/aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp:279:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cv::Mat’
    sourceAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1] = matA->getValueData(fila,columna);
             ^~
/home/ibrrahim/catkin_workspaces/aerostack_catkin_ws/src/aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp:283:32: error: ‘CV_SVD’ was not declared in this scope
     cvInvert(sourceAux,pinvAux,CV_SVD); //CV_SVD
                                ^~~~~~
/home/ibrrahim/catkin_workspaces/aerostack_catkin_ws/src/aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp:283:32: note: suggested alternative: ‘CV_SSE’
     cvInvert(sourceAux,pinvAux,CV_SVD); //CV_SVD
                                ^~~~~~
                                CV_SSE
/home/ibrrahim/catkin_workspaces/aerostack_catkin_ws/src/aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp:283:5: error: ‘cvInvert’ was not declared in this scope
     cvInvert(sourceAux,pinvAux,CV_SVD); //CV_SVD
     ^~~~~~~~
/home/ibrrahim/catkin_workspaces/aerostack_catkin_ws/src/aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/src/source/matrixLib.cpp:288:32: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cv::Mat’
    Matrix::setValueData(pinvAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1],fila,columna);
                                ^~
aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/CMakeFiles/lib_cvgutils.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'aerostack_stack/stack/libraries/lib_cvgutils/CMakeFiles/lib_cvgutils.dir/src/source/matrixLib.cpp.o' failed
```

The part of code where this occurred is:

```
int Matrix::pseudoinverse(Matrix* matA)
{
    //Comprobaciones previas
    //To do
    //Pinv calulation
    cv::Mat pinvAux=cv::Mat(Matrix::numFilas,Matrix::numColumnas,CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat sourceAux=cv::Mat(Matrix::numFilas,Matrix::numColumnas,CV_32FC1);
    for(int fila=1;fila<=numFilas;fila++)
    {
        for(int columna=1;columna<=numColumnas;columna++)
        {
            //printf("%f\n",sourceAux->data.fl[1]);
            sourceAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1] = matA->getValueData(fila,columna);
            //printf("%f\n",sourceAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1]);
        }
    }
    cvInvert(sourceAux,pinvAux,CV_SVD); //CV_SVD
    for(int fila=1;fila<=numFilas;fila++)
    {
        for(int columna=1;columna<=numColumnas;columna++)
        {
            Matrix::setValueData(pinvAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1],fila,columna);
        }
    }

    //End
    return 1;
}
```

Can you please give me some hints how to handle this datatype conversion issue, because the datatype of `sourceAux` is `cv::Mat` while `data` is pointer `float*`.

Comment: sourceAux.data[... -> should probably be sourceAux.data[... because cv::Mat is not a pointer type (where cv::Mat* instead _would_ be a pointer type).

Answer (score 0):

You have your member operator (`.`) and 'pointer-member operator' (`->`) the wrong way round. So, instead of:

```cpp
    sourceAux->data.fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1] = matA->getValueData(fila,columna);
```

you should use:

```cpp
    sourceAux.data->fl[(fila-1)*numColumnas+columna-1] = matA->getValueData(fila,columna);
```

Because `sourceAux` is an *object* (not a pointer) and, as you have said, its `data` member *is* a pointer. You should also make a similar change in the `setValueData` call, a few lines further down.